# PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected, and crash every few hours in 18.04 (3700x+RTX2070)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, pcie

After I install Ubuntu and Nvidia driver, everything looks fine, but when I press ctrl+alt+F1-F6 to entre Terminal model, I got **PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected**.

I've done some search on the web and I tried to **add pci=nomsi, but it directly cause my ubuntu unable to boot**, it freezes at the purple screen even before logging (nothing but whole purple screen). I could boot into it by using recovery mode, so I removed it from grub and my ubuntu became able to boot as normal. Then I tried to use **pcie_aspm=off**, my ubuntu was able to boot and there is no longer such error in the terminal, **but my ubuntu became extremely slow (almost freeze, crash)**, so I removed it. What can I do to solve the problem?

Also, I found that my ubuntu **usually crashes (or I can say it became nearly freeze) after about 2-4 hours every time**.

Below is my config:
CPU: AMD 3700X
GPU: ASUS Strix RTX 2070 O8G
Motherboard: ASUA ROG Strix B450-F Gaming

Is there anything wrong because my CPU is newly released?

BTW, I'm new to ubuntu and I tried a lot of methods to install ubuntu at the beginning (such as press E and edit something before installing), I found that they were not actually working, then I just installed it with let ubuntu install the driver for me without any modify in the grub. And I use the PPA method to install Nvidia driver, it looks fine and worked.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try bootoption `pci=noaer`